# Magento 2.2.6 Unable to save stock item error

Tags: magento2

We are preparing to go live with a mage 2 store but after clearing all development product data we are no longer able to save products from admin.

The error "Unable to save stock item" is shown every time we try to save a product. All other content editors work as they should.

System.log shows the following error after attempting to save:

```
[2019-04-24 01:35:26] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Unable to save Stock Item
Trace: #0 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/StockRegistry.php(180): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository->save(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Adminhtml\Stock\Item))
#1 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/SaveInventoryDataObserver.php(110): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku('Test123', Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Adminhtml\Stock\Item))
#2 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#4 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#5 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(818): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(948): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterSave()
#8 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(31): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->afterSave()
#9 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(52): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Create.php(123): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(96): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Create->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#16 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(655): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#17 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#18 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(51): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#20 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(24): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#21 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#22 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(68): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#23 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#24 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#25 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#27 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php(111): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#28 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save->execute()
#29 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(235): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#32 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#36 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#39 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#41 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#43 /var/www/html/staging.testsite.com.au/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#44 {main} [] []
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check this https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/447#issuecomment-349926468

Comment: or did you try reindex after clearing all development product?

Comment: Thanks for your response magefms, I had a look at the elasticsearch link however the development server is running a carbon copy of this installation without elasticsearch enabled and is working as expected. I have also reset and reindexed as well as flushed cache. The product clearing queries I used are listed here: https://www.titechglobal.com/magento-2-x-how-to-clear-test-data-before-production/ if that helps

Comment: The blog is missing some info. to reset order id(increment_id) you have to truncate table `sequence_order_1` also the stocks are save in a view not in table, check view `inventory_stock_1` make sure it is empty as well. hope that helps

Comment: Thanks again magefms, I'm a bit confused as to how to go about what you've mentioned. I have truncated sequence_order_1 but not sure how to check view inventory_stock_1. Can you please explain how to do this from mySQL? Thanks

Comment: ahh I mean the inventory_stock_1 is inside the view not in table, so you can check your database there is table(s) and there is view → this is where inventory_stock_1 is located. From there you can truncate it